# 'cache' controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am noticing some requests on an ASP.NET MVC 3 website I developed where it shows the URLs as:

```
URL /cache/4d3d10bd28ff623813254a49b26be41f
```

I am getting several such requests.

Can somebody guide on why would I receive such requests? There is no such controller with name "Cache".

Thank you

Comment: Where do you see this? In developer console? Server logs? Html source?

Comment: If you see it in your web logs it may be just someone blindly poking around on the web server (check to see if the web logs states whether a 200 success code or 404 page not found error code was returned).  Otherwise it might be a custom MVC route someone has added (check your Global.asax file).

Comment: In my website, I instantiate the controllers manually. So I am noticing this error on Elmah and it seems several requests have been made for "Cache/....".